# zend_mime_message class not found error

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, smtp

I'm getting class not found error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Mime_Message' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\library\Zend\Mail.php on line 53
```

I initially had Zend framework 1.11 only for smtp mail. It stopped working after I updated php to the latest version, so I thought I should also download latest Zend library. I copied the new library in the exact location where the older version was, but it still doesn't work. I checked my PHP.ini for include_path, the library is included. I don't understand why I'm still getting this error message. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest ZF version would be 2.3.1, and ZF2 is not backwards compatible. You probably need the to download the latest version of ZF1, which is 1.12.7, via: http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest

Comment: Got it!! That's what it was. Thank you @TimFountain